# Add drop down menu to top nav link bar sharepoint foundation 2013

Tags: dropdown

I'm using sharepoint foundation 2013, and i want to add an simple dropdown menu to the top link bar. I've done lots of research online but no chance to find the solution that work.
Is there someone who knows how to do it?

Any suggestions or help is very appreciated
Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: This video about SharePoint 2013 Mega Menu might help you, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83WhLBo2g6Q if not then check this article out, https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/How-to-Achieve-a-Mega-Menu-Using-Out-of-the-Box-Navigation-in-SharePoint-2013-and-jQuery.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to have an mega menu done. Just simple drop down menu. Any idea?

Comment: if you check second link, it's an example of drop down menu, did you actually went through it ?

Comment: i've cheked, but as i said i have sharepoint foundation and i don't have SHARE POINT PUBLISHING.